# Changing column names in SQL display

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, split

This is my existing code that is running error free:

```
    SELECT  ItemId,
   CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
 [Object],
 SourceSite,
 DestSite
 FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
 [Object],
 SourceSite,
 DestSite,
            UserCode
 FROM JnlMediumMove
 WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove     the time part
WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

However I need to make some changes in the display of the data.
1) Change name of Column ItemId to “Item ID”
2) Change name of Column Object to “Media”
3) Change name of Column SourcSite to “Source Site”
4) Change name of Column DestSite to “Destination Site”
5) Add a column in between Source Site and Destination Site, called “Comments”
6) Each entry in that column must contain this statement “Was successfully moved to”

Please Note: I am trying to run a batch job everyday regarding these reports.  So the column headings and changes must all be made in one single query.  Can anyone make any changes to my code to obtain the required output? That would be greatly appreciated.  I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Comment: What part can't you figure out? Did you want to change the actual column names via `alter` or simply alias the column names for this single select statement?

Comment: Did you try using aliases? Try this [SQL column alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: I got this error when I did: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: I understand the alias concept, I just have never applied it to such a long query.  @rs

Comment: @omarK, query length has nothing to do with aliases, just add aliases to columns you want to use different name for. i think you are lazy to edit your query and add aliases by yourself and want us to do your work :)

Comment: @rs I am not lazy actually I have never used aliases before that is why I have asked for help.

Comment: @omarK, ok let me show you example - `[Object] As [media], SourceSite "Source Site",...`

Comment: @rs I get this error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'Object'.

Comment: post your updated query with aliases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemID AS [Item Id]
```

Etc, etc etc? I think this is what you are asking for (aliases for column names). The rest would be similar. for the Comments column, `'Was successfully moved to' AS [Comment]` should work fine.

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT  ItemId AS [Item Id],
   CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
        SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
        SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
 [Object] AS [Media],
 SourceSite AS [Source Site],
 'Was successfully moved to' AS [Comments],
 DestSite AS [Destination Site]
 FROM (  SELECT  ItemId,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
 [Object],
 SourceSite,
 DestSite,
            UserCode
 FROM JnlMediumMove
 WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
 substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove     the time part
WHERE UserCode = 'Automation'
ORDER BY [Date] DESC;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the syntax will look like with my existing code, is it possible for you to add your suggestions to my code, so I can try running it? Thanks

Comment: LMFAO...send him you db credentials and he'll login and do your job for you.

Comment: @Mike Cheel I tried to apply the Item ID alias but it gave me this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'ID'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? also, did you enclose Item Id in brackets like this [Item Id]?

Comment: Yes I am and yes I did @Mike Cheel

Answer (score 3):

After reading all the comments so far, the problem appears to be not "how can I add a column alias to all my columns?", but "how do I know what is already named or not in the spaghetti mess of a query I have inherited?"

Let me try to help with some background info. For various historical reasons, SQL Server supports all of the following methods for renaming a column.

- *name* = *expression*
- *expression*  *name*
- *expression* `AS` *name*
- '*name*' = *expression*
- *expression* '*name*'
- *expression* `AS` '*name*'
- "*name*" = *expression*
- *expression* "*name*"
- *expression* `AS` "*name*"
- [*name*] = *expression*
- *expression* [*name*]
- *expression* `AS` [*name*]

A lot of those combinations have been sprinkled freely across your query in the past. Presumably every developer who has worked on it has applied his/her own style.

I suggest you go through each column expression and systematically convert them to one consistent syntax. The last one in the list is probably the safest and most modern. It would also help if you align the column aliases to a specific tab stop in your text editor. Once you have done that, it should be a very simple matter to apply the column names that you have been asked to do.

Comment: Just note that the format `"name" = expression` is deprecated in SQL Server. Also in SQL Server, many of us use `name = expression` for its superior clarity ( you never have to hunt for the alias at the end of a huge expression).